# I want to use product foreign key but it is too slow

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    ean = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    inventory = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sales_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=15, blank=True, null=True)
    web_shop_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=15, blank=True, null=True)
    bb_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=15, blank=True, null=True)
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    categorie = models.ForeignKey(Categorie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    # slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
```

As you can see, This is not a small amount of queries.

```
class SaleItem(models.Model):
 
    invoice_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(auto_created=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have about 15000+ Item models registered in database. therefore when i use the foreign key in SaleItem model, it takes too much time, drops performance.
I am using Jawsdb(a 10$ plan) and Mysql. I think other than the huge data, its because the ram of the database is shared. This is taking my life. I need help seriously.

Comment: 15000 items is not a lot for a database. you should post what query are you launching to the database.

Comment: what queries I am launching to the database? Sorry,I don't understand the question actually

Comment: You said "it takes too much time", but you didn't say what takes too much time. Like Sembei said, 15000 records is a very small db table, so almost any query should be fast.

Comment: you have just posted a class definition. Your code will have to launch some queries to the database to retrieve data and fill those classes. You need to post the relevant part of your code so we can see how you are retrieving data from the database.

Comment: Well, I do not have any other functions that fetch data or anything, Its just when I select the foreign key dropdown list of SaleItem class in django admin panel, the dropdown list takes upto 5 secs to appear and hangs for 1 sec or 2

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the generated `SELECT`.  (I don't speak DJango.)

Answer (score 0):

If you fetch `SaleItem`s and then for each `SaleItem`, you access the `.product`, it will each time make a query to fetch that specific `product`. You can fetch all the related `Item`s with the same query with `.select_related(..)`:

```
SaleItem.objects.select_related('product')
```

Comment: Well, I do not have any other functions that fetch data or anything, Its just when I select the foreign key dropdown list of SaleItem class in django admin panel, the dropdown list takes upto 5 secs to appear and hangs for 1 sec or 2

Comment: @Sesshōmaru: well that queryset will likely fetch the `product` somehow. In the `ModelAdmin` you can use `queryset = SaleItem.objects.select_related('product')`.